# PIC Assembly - Return without branching out

Tags: assembly, pic

```
.
.
btfsc STATUS,Z
goto loop
.
.
loop: return
```

How does this code behave? *goto* is not branching out, so nothing is saved on the stack? There are no *call*s in the code as well.

Answer (score 0):

`goto`  and `btfsc` instructions both affect the program counter, not the stack.

In your snippet if the `Z` bit of the `STATUS` register is set then program counter advances  to the next instruction. The `goto` instruction executes changing the program counter to the address of the `return` instruction at the label `loop`. The `return` instruction will set the program counter to the return address on the stack. There must be a valid return address on the stack at that point. If the stack is not set the resulting jump is unpredictable.

If the `Z` bit is clear then the program counter ‘skips’ and is advanced to the next instruction after the `goto` instruction where program execution will continue.

Comment: Yes, I understand the basics. I should've stated my question differently, but I rushed it because I have an exam in the subject tomorrow. From experimenting with it I noticed that after the *return* line is executed it goes back to the very beginning of the program. Which would make a lot of sense since the stack is empty, so there is no reference to where to return to. So naturally it goes back to the beginning of the code. I am not sure if this is the case in 100% of the times though.

Comment: No, it will not necessarily go to the beginning of  the code. Return will load the contents of the current stack memory location – whatever it is – into the program counter. If the stack is not set the resulting jump is unpredictable.